# Horizontal scrollbar in APEX 4.2.1 Classic report

Tags: oracle-apex

To enable horizontal scrollbars in a table I need to style the containing DIV with "overflow: auto", highlighted in blue.

[image: Control the style of the DIV containing the table]

I tried it with FireBug and got the desired result.  Just can't figure out out how to put the setting into APEX.

Using the theme "Blue Responsive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played with this a bit in Apex 4.2.2, it should work the same in 4.2.1 I think. That particular div doesn't come from any template but you can target it with some CSS.

In the page properties, for CSS Inline, I entered the following and it seemed to work:

```
#report_2583625959157728_catch {overflow:auto}
```

(I think I've transcribed the correct id from your screenshot - you may need to check)

Unfortunately this means you'd have to do this for each report in your application individually where you want the scrollbar to appear.

Note: I haven't tested this in IE, however - last time I was mucking around with scrolling areas I found it incredibly frustrating to get it working in IE without breaking other functionality in the region - especially for Interactive reports.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to Region Header:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
```

and to Region Footer

```
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add your css line to a report region template, if you want the scrollbar to be added to each report.
Other wise you're better of putting the overflow on a class and add it to your application's stylesheet, eg:
.myClass {overflow:auto}

you get more flexibilty to style your region this way. You can add the class to your report by setting the region attributes to class="myClass".

Note that instead of "auto", you can also try to use the element option "scroll", check the w3schools docs: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Have you tried this? i.e. how did you target this particular part as it's not actually *in the region template* (as far as I can tell, it seems to be generated by Apex, not from the template)

Comment: Region attributes don't get added at this node (they get applied to the `<section>` node, so the "myClass" method doesn't work, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Possibly you could use this though to create a selector which targets the specific region within the section container. This depends on the theme/template you'd be using of course. Also, setting a static ID and doing the same would obtain the same but be less generic (if applicable)